# MySQL returns empty array when querying longitude and latitude

Tags: mysql, express

I want to retrieve data from my mysql database via an api query in longitude and latitude.

If I query through the placeName column, it returns all the data.
If I query through the id column, it returns all the data.

But using both longitude and latitude columns, an empty array is returned. This is the response:

```
{
"status": 200,
"data": [],
"message": "Longitude and latitude retrieved successfully"
```

}

This is the code:

```
let sql = "select * from sampleData where lng=-73.981750 and lat=40.781040";

connection.query(sql,((err, data, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send({
        status: 200,
        data,
        message: "Longitude and latitude retrieved successfully"
    })
}));
```

UPDATE:

This is the table and query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sampleData` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `placeName` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `lng` DECIMAL(11,6) NOT NULL,
  `lat` DECIMAL(11,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

INSERT INTO `sampleData` (`id`, `placeName`, `lng`, `lat`) VALUES
  ('1','Citarella Gourmet Market - Upper West Side', ' -73.981750', '40.781040'),
  ('2','Bloomingdale The Outlet Store', '-73.982090 ', '40.779130');

select * from `sampleData` where lng="-73.981750" and lat="40.781040";
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/445322/2/0

This is what I want for the output when express returns the MySQL response to the client:

```
{
"status": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "placeName": "Citarella Gourmet Market - Upper West Side",
        "lng": "-73.981750",
        "lat": "40.781040"
    }
],
"message": "Longitude and latitude retrieved successfully"
```

}

Comment: Easy answer. A row with this lat and long data does not exists in the database

Comment: @Strawberry I updated the question and added an sql fiddle.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/445322/2/0

Comment: Remove the quotation marks from your query

Comment: @Strawberry tried doing that. Still does the same: returns empty array.

Comment: I'm confused. Plainly, your fiddle returns the desired result (minus the 'status' wrapper)